# Object won't read in properly

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm writing a program that writes an array object to a java binary file then it is read back in. The problem is when the array is read back in it is returning [null, null]. Am I not reading/writing the object correctly?

DBMS.java

```
public static void writeToFile(Datab[] friends) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream myStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream("datt.dat"));
        for(int i=0; i<friends.length; i++){
        myStream.writeObject(friends[i]);
        }
        myStream.close();
    }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nArray written to file datt.");
}

/**********************************************************
 * readFromFile Read from the binary file and return the array of objects to
 * the calling method Catch the following exceptions: FileNotFoundException,
 * ClassNotFoundException, and the IOException (know what each does!)
 * 
 * @return The array as read in from the binary input file
 */
public static Datab[] readFromFile() {
    System.out
            .println("\n\nNow let's reopen the file and display the array.");
    Datab[] b = null;

    // The name of the file to open.
    String fileName = "datt.dat";

    try {
        // Use this for reading the data.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];

        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("datt.dat"));

        input.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
        // Or we could just do this:
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;

}
```

Output:
The array before writing it to the output file:

```
[Robert , Duchar 7345555555, Len , Gt 7345555567]
```

Array written to file datt.

Now let's reopen the file and display the array.

The array as read in from the input file...
Would you like to see the array backwards or forwards? 
Enter the Your answer (b or f): f

```
[null, null]
```

Comment: You create an inputstream, but don't actually read anything.

Comment: You do read InputStream but not save in any array. Expected b[i] = input.Something

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring b with a `null` value initialization.

```
Datab[] b = null;
```

Then you are nowhere updating value of `b`

Then finally you are returning `b` which is initialzed to `null`